# Getting sum of rows with same id in SQL to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help to get some of two rows with the same id:
I know the SQL code for this which is:

```
SELECT orderID,sum(itemPrice) as sum FROM orderitems GROUP BY orderID;
```

But I don't know how to implement this in PHP.
Here is my code :

```
   <?php
    require('database.php');
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `orderitems`';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $addresses = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();



    $order_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'order_id');

    $total='SELECT SUM(itemPrice)  
            FROM orderitems 
            group by orderID';
    $statement = $db->prepare($total);
    $statement->execute();
    $total_order= $statement->fetchAll();


    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Total of the order</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />

        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>
                Total for an order 
            </h1>
            <h4>
                <label>orderID : </label> <?php echo $order_id ;?>


            </h4>
            <p>The total for this order consisting of :</p>

            <p><?php echo $total_order; ?>

            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

But it is not showing the result instead write simple `ARRAY`
I even tried `var_dumb` but then it shows like that:

> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["SUM(itemPrice)"]=> string(6) "399.00" [0]=> string(6) "399.00" } [1]=> array(2) { ["SUM(itemPrice)"]=> string(6) "699.00" [0]=> string(6) "699.00" } [2]=> array(2) { ["SUM(itemPrice)"]=> string(7) "1048.99" [0]=> string(7) "1048.99" } }

It shows the right answer but I wanna get rid of this others things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a simple foreach

```
    $total='SELECT SUM(itemPrice)   as sum
        FROM orderitems 
        group by orderID';
    $statement = $db->prepare($total);
    $statement->execute();
    $total_order= $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($total_order as $row) {
       echo $row['sum'] . ' <br />';
    }
```

in this juts an echo but you can add to div

Comment: yeah cool thanx a lot just one more favour pls how to get just one sum with each different id

Comment: Explain better you need onky the first result  or or somethings else

Comment: Done Thanx  a lot

Answer (score 2):

two suggestions:

(1) Your source-code indicates that you want to select a specific orderId. So your second prepared SQL statement is missing the WHERE clause that would achieve that. Or, alternatively, the second statement is missing the column `orderID` which you could use to access the appropriate row, from the fetched result.

(2) The way you fetched your result produced an array with each element consisting of one of the rows selected by your second statement. You still have to select the targeted row. And after you selected that row, you also will have to access the appropriate column. So, for the sake of argument, let's say the second row in you "var-dump" example is the desired one. You would access it like thus:

```
<p><?php echo $total_order[1]['sum(itemPrice)']; ?>
```